# Connections and tensor fields

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, tensors, connections

Let $T$ be a $(1, 1)$ tensor field, $\lambda$ a covector field and $X, Y$ vector fields. We may define $\nabla_X T$ by requiring the ‘inner’ Leibniz rule, $$\nabla_X[T(\lambda, Y )] = (\nabla_XT)(\lambda, Y ) + T(\nabla_X \lambda, Y ) + T(\lambda, \nabla_X Y ) . $$

(a) Prove that $\nabla_XT$ defines a $(1, 1)$ tensor field.

(b) Prove that the components of the $(1, 2)$ tensor $\nabla T$ are, $$\nabla_cT^{a}_{\,\,\,b} = e_c(T^{a}_{b}) + \Gamma^{a}_{\,\,dc}T^{d}_{b} − \Gamma^{d}_{ bc}T^{a}_{d}$$
(c) Deduce that the Kronecker delta tensor is covariantly constant $\nabla \delta = 0.$

Attempt:

Really just need to check what I am going to do is correct.  For a), $\nabla_X T$ defines a (1,1) tensor if it is linear in the arguments $X$ and $Y$? Linear in $X$ by definition of a connection and for $Y$;

$$\nabla_X (T (\lambda, fY)) = (\nabla_X T)(\lambda fY) + T(\nabla_X \lambda, fY) + T(\lambda, \nabla_X (fY)) $$ which can be written using the axioms of a connection $$ f(\nabla_X T)(\lambda, Y) + fT(\nabla_X \lambda, Y) + fT(\lambda, f \nabla_X Y) + T(\lambda, X(f)Y)$$ It doesn't seem to be linear in Y at all?

Thanks!

Comment: Note you need to use product rule on both sides to see that $Xf$ is cancelled.

Comment: Ok, so I need to show that $\nabla_x T$ is $C^{\infty}(M)$ linear , which is to say it is linear in its arguments $\lambda$ and $Y$? So let $\lambda \rightarrow f\lambda$ and $Y \rightarrow fY$?

Comment: I have a general expression for the components of the covariant derivative of an $(r,s)$ tensor, and so b) is done in a line. But I am just wondering if you knew how the result b) comes about from first principles? In our notes, the generic formula is given as a definition.

Comment: @John sorry, forgot to tag you.

Comment: Yes, you need to show that $\nabla_X T$ is $C^\infty (M)$ linear. (b) can be found by using the definition as stated in the question.

Comment: @John  I see. Could you maybe elaborate on how to use the definition in the question to get b)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your definition,

$$ (\nabla_XT)(\lambda, Y ) = \nabla_X[T(\lambda, Y )] - T(\nabla_X \lambda, Y ) - T(\lambda, \nabla_X Y ) . $$

To calculate $\nabla_i T^j_{\ k}$, note (We use the simplified notation $\partial_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$)

$$\nabla_i T^j_{\ k} =  (\nabla_{\partial _j} T)(dx^j , \partial_k) = \nabla_{\partial_i}[T(dx^j , \partial_k )] - T(\nabla_{\partial_i} dx^j,\partial_k ) - T(dx^j, \nabla_{\partial_i} \partial _k ) $$

$$ = \partial_i (T^j_{\ k}) + T(\Gamma_{il}^j dx^l , \partial_k) - T(dx^j , \Gamma_{ik}^l \partial_l) $$

$$ = \partial_i (T^j_{\ k}) + \Gamma_{il}^j T( dx^l , \partial_k) - \Gamma_{ik}^l T(dx^j ,  \partial_l) = \partial_i (T^j_{\ k}) + \Gamma_{il}^j T^l_{\ k} - \Gamma_{ik}^l T^j_{\ l}. $$

**Remark:**
First of all $T^j_{\ k} = T(dx^j , \partial_k)$ by definition, so $\nabla_{\partial_i}[T(dx^j , \partial_k )]= \partial_i (T^j_{\ k})$. Secondly, we **define** the covariant differentiation of a covector field $\alpha$ so that

$$ \nabla_{X} \big( \alpha(Y)\big) = (\nabla_X \alpha) (Y) + \alpha (\nabla_XY)$$

is satisfied. In particular, written in local coordinate,

$$0 = \nabla_{\partial_i} (dx^j (\partial_k)) = \nabla_{\partial_i} dx^j (\partial_k) + dx^j (\nabla_{\partial_i} \partial_k) = \nabla_{\partial_i} dx^j (\partial_k) + \Gamma_{ik}^j$$

$$\Rightarrow \nabla_{\partial_i} dx^j = -\Gamma_{ik}^j dx^k.$$

Comment: Thanks very much. A few follow up questions if that is ok: As far as I understand, the first term on the RHS, $\nabla_{\partial_i} T^j_k$, has been simplified to $\partial_i T^{j}_k$. Could you explain this?  Also, the only definition I have in my notes is the following: $\nabla_a e_b = \Gamma^c_{ba}e_c$. Is the generalisation to a covector field basis given by $$\nabla_a f^c = -\Gamma^c_{da}f^d,$$ which I think you have used in the above. Thanks!

Comment: @CAF: Please see the edit of the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Yes it makes sense. Just a notational question: In the first line of the proof of the final equation, you wrote $$\nabla_X (\alpha (Y)) \rightarrow \nabla_i (dx^j (\partial_k))$$ Why does $\nabla_X \rightarrow \nabla_i$ here and not $\nabla_{\partial_i}$ as you used in the subsequent terms?

Comment: @CAF: It should be $\nabla_{\partial_i}$. Let me fix that.

Comment: Many thanks! +1 and accepted